# Convert trial output to junit xml

Tags: python, junit, report

How could `trial` output be converted to JUnit xml format? There is no such possible report format in `trial`.

```
$> trial --help-reporters
Trial's output can be customized using plugins called Reporters. You can
select any of the following reporters using --reporter=<foo>

    subunit     subunit output
    bwverbose   Colorless verbose output
    text    terse text output
    verbose     verbose color output (default reporter)
    timing  Timing output
    summary     minimal summary output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is by setting the reporter of trial to be subunit and then convert the output to JUnit via the `subunit2junitxml` found in subunit (under the filters [folder](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~subunit/subunit/trunk/files/head:/filters/) in trunk).

For example we do:

```
trial --reporter=subunit | subunit2junitxml --forward --output-to=junitxml-result.xml
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a hard time with this.  Turns out subunit has a new version 2 of it's protocol, and that's what the version of subunit2junitxml was expecting.  See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-subunit

I had to pipe the results of trial through the subunit-1to2 filter before piping to subunit2junitxml.  So the command I ended up with is:

```
trial --reporter=subunit <mypackage> | subunit-1to2 | subunit2junitxml --no-passthrough --output-to=$WORKSPACE/temp/output.xml
```

Hope this helps someone.